# How to Calculate Daily Active Users(DAU) in big query to get the same result as Firebase Analytics dashboard

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm calculating DAU using the following query in `Big Query`

```
select  count(user_pseudo_id)as DAU from 
                (
                    SELECT user_pseudo_id FROM
                    `myProj.mydataset.events_*`
                    WHERE       
                    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210504' AND '20210504'
                    and LOWER(platform) = 'android'
                    and event_name like 'session_start'
                    group by user_pseudo_id
                )
```

And for the specified date I get `17748` as a result.
For the same date Firebase shows `17186`

I want to understand how actually Firebase calculates this value, since
the count of `session_start` event both in Firebase and Big Query DB is the same `25890`

Comment: There might be duplicates in your table, have you tried SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id ?

Comment: Since I'm using `group by user_pseudo_id` statement in nested query, the duplicate problem won't exist.

Comment: Sorry you're totally right, I had missed that. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Firebase analytics so without the data I cannot help you. The only thing coming to my mind would be to check whether it's not a timezone issue: there might be a few hours gap between UTC and your timezone, which can maybe explain a different number of users...

Comment: Yeah, I've considered the timezone case, but I'm almost sure that firebase analytics calculated DAU based on `session_start` event, and since the count of sessions for a certain day is exactly the same, I think I don't have a timezone issue. Also the number of installs is the same in BQ and Firebase.